# Autobahn PHP client

Tags: php, websocket, autobahn

I have a python autobahn script (websock) running and working perfectly with the browser, i need to send data from another server running PHP to the python server. is there any PHP websock clients that are compatible with the latest autobahn (websock) protocol ?

i have tried some, but neither worked
like this one

> https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket/blob/master/client/test_server.php

it didn't !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ronan,

Take a look at the [Thruway](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway) project.  It's a WAMPv2 PHP client/server that's compatible with the current version of autobahn.js.

You can also find more information on how to create a simple PHP client [here.](http://voryx.net/creating-a-custom-php-wamp-client-for-thruway/)

Comment: Nice project, didn't test it though, switched to python as PHP takes too much resources !, but still handling website stuff with PHP with a TCP connection between the PHP and python app ... works great !